# Angularjs ng-change triggering control

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angularjs

I have a ng-change on a text field and the function is called as expected:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="toggleState" ng-change="ToggleGroupVisiable()" data-rule"" />
```

My question is how do I reference the value of the text box (that is being changed) in the function ToggleGroupVisiable() which is called on changes.

```
    $scope.ToggleGroupVisiable = function () {

     ... some code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be bound with the ng-model. So something like $scope.toggleState.